# Will using memcache reduce my instance memory?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm currently running into soft memory errors on my Google App Engine app because of high memory usage.  A number of large objects are driving memory usage sky high.

I thought perhaps if I set and recalled them from memcache maybe that might reduce overall memory usage.  Reading through the docs this doesn't seem to be the case, and that the benefit of memcache is to reduce HRD queries.

Does memcache impact overall memory positively or negatively?

Edit: I know I can upgrade the instance class to F2 but I'm trying to see if I can remain on the least expensive while reducing memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving objects to and from Memcache will have no impact on your memory unless you destroy these objects in your Java code or empty collections.

A bigger problem is that memcache entities are limited to 1MB, and memcache is not guaranteed. The first of these limitations means that you cannot push very large objects into Memcache.

The second limitations means that you cannot easily replace, for example, a HashMap with memcache - it's impossible to tell if getValue() returns null because an object is not present or because it was bumped out of memcache. So you will have to make an extra call each time to a datastore to see if an object is really not present.

Comment: This is generally true thou I can see cases where memcache could help. If the code uses a lot of memory to compute a small result maybe the result can be cached thus reducing the need to compute it and reducing memory usage. If the question was less vague about the scenario it would be easier to give alternatives

Comment: I am not sure how caching a small object (result) will reduce memory usage. Typically, you need a lot of memory when you have to read a lot of data into memory and you cannot discard it until the very end. I agree though that there are many ways to reduce memory usage, especially if loops and collections are involved.

Comment: Thanks both.  My scenario is I have many requests to read the same blob without altering it.  Loading it over and over across many requests seems to push the memory usage over 128mb

Comment: Re andrei because you save recalculating the value from a possibly memory intensive source. OP should instead consider keeping the objects in global memory (with proper considerstion for parallel requests to the same instance) if you are having many simultaneous requests and are generating copies of it.

Comment: It seems like there is a memory leak in your implementation. Loading the same blob many times should have no impact on your memory beyond the maximum number of parallel requests, and using Memcache will most likely help in your scenario - not with memory, but to speed up the response time. Check that you close readers when you read a blob and consider using a global static variable to ensure that you have only one copy in instance memory.

Comment: Thanks guys - I'm now under the working assumption of a memory leak.  I'll start googling for memory profiling solutions.  Also I'll look to put it in memcache regardless.

Comment: There must be a memory leak - I've loaded a page that just prints 'runtime.memory_usage().current()' and every refresh this value increases.

Comment: @user1961 re: reading single blob from memcache. It depends on the key size and the rate you plan to fetch it, but I figured someone has to mention it before you run into scaling issues: distribute the load across your memcache keyspace. Check this for more details: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/best-practices-for-app-engine-memcache